# JPA mapping external classes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

I'm using a project with hibernate 5.1.1 and i'm trying to map some classes from an API I use in my project (so i cant annote them).

```
@Entity
public class Activity implements Runnable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false, orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity=AuthData.class)
private AuthData authData = null; //AuthData is from an external API, I know its source code, but i cant insert the annotations in it.
```

Comment: So what is your question? And those classes are annotated?

Comment: My question is how to do hibernate recognize those classes because as I said i can annote them

Answer (score 1):

Just because you can't touch the code for a class doesn't mean you can't make a class a JPA entity. Just specify an *orm.xml* file and [define the class in there](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/metadata_xml.html).